# Caching Client in Jersey 2

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0

We are in process of migraring from Jersey 1 to 2. As part of this, I am trying to move caching configurations in Jersey 1.

With Jersey 1, we were using ApacheHttpClient4 which internally was using a ApacheHttpClient4Handler built using CachingHttpClient.

```
ApacheHttpClient4Handler httpClientHandler = new ApacheHttpClient4Handler(cachingHttpClient, null, false);
javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = new ApacheHttpClient4(httpClientHandler, clientConfig);
```

But looks like ApacheHttpClient4Handler is not available in Jersey 2.

Question here is, is there an alternative to ApacheHttpClient4Handler available?

I know how caching works as a server (Setting response headers etc). My question here is executing the external cacheable REST requests which my Jersey Client can cache.

Long term goal is to move away with Jersey comletely and use something like RestTemplate. But for now I am trying for a short term solution.

Any help here will be much appreciated.